# onclick append <a>item</a> text to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Been searching for an hour now and still couldn't find a simple solution for this,
seems like people are suggesting using jquery and long scripts that really doesn't make sense to me;

sorry if I am being ignorant about this!

what I'm trying to do should be fairly simple and will sincerely appreciate it if some one can step in and complete the javascript portion. I have to admit, I lack the skill or knowledge to do this and the research I've done had lead me to answers that I couldn't combine with what I'm trying to do.

```
<textarea id="cartlist">items will be copied here when you click on them</textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="trigger the add to list function">item name 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="trigger the add to list function">item name 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="trigger the add to list function">item name 3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="trigger the add to list function">item name 4</a>
```

in simple words:
onclick append and adds the text to textarea
similar to a grocery list, where you can click on a certain  element and onclick will be automatically added to the  list.

(milk,sugar, bacon, etc..)

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I can not understand your purpose. What you want to achieve ?!

Comment: Please review [ask]. It seems you haven't actually asked a question. Be sure to include a [mcve] showing what you've tried and where you had trouble. Be aware that [we expect you to have invested your own time into research first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/497418).

Comment: Looks like you are asking us to code... WRITE YOUR OWN CODE

Comment: I've rephrased my question, I'm sorry - hopefully it makes more sense this time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With simple pure js function you can do this

```js
function CopyToTextarea(el){
  var text = el.textContent;
  var textarea = document.getElementById('cartlist');
  textarea.value = textarea.value + text +'\n';
}
```

```css
#cartlist{
  width : 100%;
  height : 100px;
  line-height : 30px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="cartlist"></textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item name 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item name 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item name 3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item name 4</a>
```

**Update #1** up to OP comment *is there any way to determine if I click on it again, than it will take action and remove the item from the list?*

```js
function CopyToTextarea(el){
  var text = el.textContent,                           // get this <a> text
      textarea = document.getElementById('cartlist'),  // textarea id
      textareaValue = textarea.value,                  // text area value
      Regex = new RegExp(text + '\n', 'g'),            // make new regex with <a> text and \n line break 
      textareaValue = textareaValue.indexOf(text+'\n') > -1 ?  textareaValue.replace(Regex, '') : textareaValue + text+'\n'; // this is something similar to if statement .. mean if the textarea has the <a> text and after it line break .. replace it with its line break to blank (remove it) .. if not its not on textarea add this <a> text to the textarea value
  textarea.value = textareaValue ;                     // change the textarea value with the new one
}
```

```css
#cartlist{
  width : 100%;
  height : 100px;
  line-height : 30px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="cartlist"></textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item name 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item name 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item name 3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item name 4</a>
```

Comment: Wow, much appreciated good sir, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @user3151178 you're welcome .. but this answer is simple because you  just need to append/add items to textarea .. the long answers you read before that's for sure because of checks .. something like if the item added don't add it again or something like that .. that's why another codes may be long .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: Worked like a charm, my following question is - is there any way to determine if I click on it again, than it will take action and remove the item from the list?

Comment: @user3151178 please read the comments inside the code to understand what is going on .. Good Luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: No jQuery or other libraries needed.

```js
var cartlist = document.querySelector('#cartlist');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-item]');

[].forEach.call(items, function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(){
        cartlist.value += "\n" + item.innerHTML;
    });
});
```

```css
#cartlist {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="cartlist">items will be copied here when you click on them</textarea>
<br />
<a href="#" data-item="1">item name 1</a>
<a href="#" data-item="2">item name 2</a>
<a href="#" data-item="3">item name 3</a>
<a href="#" data-item="4">item name 4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  var txtarea = $('#cartlist').val();
  var txt = $(e.target).text();
  $('#cartlist').val(txtarea + txt + '\n');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="cartlist"></textarea>
<a href="#">item name 1</a>
<a href="#">item name 2</a>
<a href="#">item name 3</a>
<a href="#">item name 4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```js
var cartElement = document.getElementById("cartlist");

function trigger(event) {
  var item = event.innerHTML;
  cartElement.append(item + "\n");
}
```

```html
<textarea id="cartlist"></textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="trigger(this)">item name 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="trigger(this)">item name 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="trigger(this)">item name 3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="trigger(this)">item name 4</a>
```